# Thunderbird portable with wine not starting from Cinnamon file explorer

Tags: wine, thunderbird, cinnamon

With remote working, I work 50% at the office on a Windows 10 machine and 50% at home on an Ubuntu machine. I solved most of my portability issued with servers on VPN, git, copies at the end of the day and I-don't-remember-what-else, but for my mail I had to resort to a portable Thunderbird installation on a pendrive. For months I could start Thunderbird on the Ubuntu machine simply opening the file explorer in Cinnamon (it's "nemo", isn't it?), then right-clicking on the Thunderbird icon and selecting "Open with wine": now this "doesn't work"™, while it does work normally if I simply run "wine path-to-thunderbird" in a terminal. This is mildly annoying, because then that instance of the terminale gets all the standard error, so I have to send the process to background, disown it and close the terminal.

I put a trademark symbol after "it doesn't work" since I know that it's not an useful description, but I really don't know how to get further hints for a problem that shows in the GUI but not from the terminal. Any suggestion?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using with the Cinnamon DE?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 focal, Cinnamon 4.4.8